# Xamarin forms app becomes unresponsive when the system time changes while app is minimized

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin.uwp

Any idea why changing system time while Xamarin forms application running background causes issues like the application are unresponsive and buttons are not working etc?

I started the Xamarin forms UWP application, then I switched it to work in the background. I changed the system time by subtracting a few hours. After returning to the application it was unresponsive and the buttons are not working. I debugged the application, but I didn't see any reason for this kind of behaviour. The same thing happens on Android and iOS. I am using Xamarin.Forms version 5.0.0.1874.

Steps to reproduce:-

1- Open Xamarin App

2- Go to your main page

3- Minimize app and change system time

4- Open App again and perform any operation if it is working correct Repeat steps 2 & 3

5- Open App again and observe it is now unresponsive

Is it Xamarin form related issue or it is happening for other frameworks as well?

Any suggestions/ideas on why is it occurring and how to handle it?

Comment: Change your [output verbosity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-view-save-and-configure-build-log-files?view=vs-2019#to-change-the-amount-of-information-included-in-the-build-log) and keep an eye on output to find some lead.

Comment: 1) Does it also happen if you *add* a few hours? If not, that is a clue that something doesn't like going backwards in time. 2) If you make a new project, with nothing in it, does it happen to that project? 3) Assuming (2) is good, copy your project to a new project, and start REMOVING stuff. At some point, it should start working. ISOLATE the specific feature or line of code that causes the problem. 4) You've tagged your question with xamarin.android, xamarin.ios - have you TESTED on those PLATFORMS? If not, then please remove those tags.

Comment: I have tested it on Android as well but it is still reproducible.  It is happening for future time and past time

Comment: Did you try  with new sample project?

Comment: Yes, there it is working fine

Comment: Then, there maybe something in your project cause the problem, could you give us a sample link or something like that.